# I want to change the distance between my image and text and also move all of the items to the left like in image two

Tags: html, css

The two main problems is the icons aren't close to the corresponding text I tried padding but it didn't work but that could have just been me, The second problem is the text is in the center of the page I think that might be the CSS because I added center so that the text would be centered to the image but maybe it's affecting everything. This is the example I'm trying to make it look like.

[my website][1]
[example website][2]

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="javascript" href="javascript/script.js">
    

</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/102/three.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<style>
Body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
}

.img-with-text {
    text-align: center;
    width: [width of img];
}

.img-with-text img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

<!-- <img src="images\Aboutme.png" alt="rorschach">
<img src="images\Contact.png" alt="Holding hands"> -->

<div class="img-with-text">
    <img src="images\Folder.png" alt="A folder" />
    <p>Projects</p>
</div>

<div class="img-with-text">
    <img src="images\Aboutme.png" alt="rorschach" />
    <p>About me</p>
</div>

<div class="img-with-text">
    <img src="images\Contact.png" alt="Holding hands" />
    <p>Contact</p>
    
</div>
    
<div class="img-with-text">
    <img src="images\Ideas.png" alt="Holding hands" />
    <p>Contact</p>
    
</div>
</html>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfjQC.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7BeK.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [1] and [2] are the same image, so it doesn't help much.

Regarding the problem of moving the items to the left, I would suggest to wrap all `<div class="img-with-text">` items in a `<div class="items">` and set for it:

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

This way you have more control over your items.

About the distance between the text and image, `<p>` always comes with a default margin (top and bottom)...so maybe it could be that? If you wanna try it out just put:

```css
.img-with-text p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

A screenshot with your elements being inspected would help to visualize what you want.